# How to run an older version of macOS in VirtualBox on new Mac?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, osx-el-capitan, apple

I currently use a iMac Mini with macOS Ventura. I have some older software that I ran on my previous Mac that I would like to use that won't run on my new machine.

Can I set up a VM in VirtualBox to run my older version of macOS X. I was using macOS el Capitan.

Comment: Since the machine is a Mac, the answer is most likely yes.  You need the install media for the older Mac.  Virtual Box, New Machine and set it up.

Comment: @John - VB cannot emulate an X64/86 CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility is if you can persuade it to run in [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) which runs on [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org)

None of the usual Mac VM apps can run x86 code at all - Parallels, VMWare, VirtualBox etc.

Comment: Is this solution free? Does it support M1 (my new mac have M1)?

Comment: Did you look at the links?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a layman... I don't really understand. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: The UTM web site contains more information than I have time or patience to copy/paste here. You just need to read it.

Comment: Oracle does have beta version of VirtualBox for Apple Silicon. The version *"can run some guest operating systems for Intel x86/x64 CPUs in an
emulation".

Comment: Interesting & promising. Hadn't seen that yet.